# Use option select to trigger jquery without button

Tags: jquery

Say I have a dropdown menu...

```
<select id="menu">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
   <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

When I select the option (without clicking a button), I want it to fire to a jQuery function. How would I go about doing this from the option select without clicking a button (just on select)? I think I would need a jQuery call on the menu id first to do this but not sure where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You should use the jQuery `change` event.

#### Sample

```
​$("#menu").change(function() {
    alert("fire your function");
});​​​​​
```

#### Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/UHmSk/)

#### More Information

- [jQuery - change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event should fire when you select something from the `select` and you can add an event handler with [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

```
$('#menu').change(function () {
    //your code
});
```

I would advise you to study the [jQuery manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#menu").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```